# Heroku pg:info gives 0 tables

Tags: database, heroku

my heroku app has dev plan

the app is useable and works and if I use pg:backups to download a backup and view it locally I can see that it has data..

however, when I do `heroku pg:info` it gives me 0 tables and 0 rows..

```
Connections: 0
Created:     2012-10-25 09:18 UTC
Data Size:   6.1 MB
Fork/Follow: Unavailable
PG Version:  9.1.6
Plan:        Dev
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Status:      available
Tables:      0
```

what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to resolve itself after a few days..

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that pg:info prints invalid data about your database when you create a new database with a new plan and you restore data into that new database from the old one. Especially the data size is shown as 0 even though it is the same size as your old database.

Answer (score 0):

I observed this too. I just upgraded to a dev plan. It is really confusing.

I was able to "test" the upgrade on my staging app before doing it on production.