# Migrating a Heroku Postgres Database from a Dev to Basic Plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've followed Heroku's guide on migrating my postgres database from a Dev to Basic Plan: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-a-dev-to-a-basic-database

Everything seems to have gone well but i'm a little confused by the info below. Even though the new basic DB is showing some data, it's not showing any tables. The data size is also different. Before I remove my Dev DB, has anyone else seen the same? Can anyone explain what's happening here?

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:dashboard ryanberry$ heroku pg:info -a myapp(replaced with my app name)
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE (DATABASE_URL)
Plan         Basic
Status       available
Connections  4
PG Version   9.1.5
Created      2012-10-29 10:51 UTC
Data Size    111.6 MB
Tables       0
Fork/Follow  Unavailable
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL
Plan         Dev
Status       available
Connections  0
PG Version   9.1.5
Created      2012-10-20 02:26 UTC
Data Size    112.4 MB
Tables       30
Rows         389702/10000 (Write access revoked)
Fork/Follow  Unavailable
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

pg:info does not show realtime info. See [Heroku pg:info gives 0 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065878/heroku-pginfo-gives-0-tables)
and
[Heroku Row Count Incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701711/heroku-row-count-incorrect) for posts with similar issues.

By now the info should display the correct amount of tables.
To be sure that the table structure is correct you can connect to the database and display all tables:

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE
\dt
```

Of course you can also do `heroku run console` to check your data in the rails console. Your application is already using your basic plan database (HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE) so if the application is running normally everything went well.